# SFDX: enable Lightning debug mode and disable component cacheing

Tags: salesforcedx

Is it possible to set default org configuration to:

- Enable "Debug Mode" is Lightning Components settings under setup
- Disable "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" in Session Settings under setup

Both of these are causing us to miss and introduce quite a bit of bugs :(

Comment: Updated my answer. There's a new org preference for Caching at least

Answer (score 10):

As of February 2018 you can use `S1EncryptedStoragePref2` as disabled OrgPreference to disable secure and persistent caching.

Update November 2018: Debug Mode can be achieved by updating the Boolean `UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref` on [sObject User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm).

Comment: Excellent, seems to be working! Although pref name seems weird :D

Comment: added info about user debug mode

Comment: Here's a one-liner to enable debug mode `echo "update new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref=true);" | sfdx force:apex:execute`

Comment: Wow!  Looking through all the Session Settings to identify "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance".  I never would have found that!